# Building SQL query IN, using python ORM

Tags: python, orm

I would like to do a query like this:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IN (value1, value2, ...);
```

using python ORM.

My current code looks:

```
# list_active_fugitives = [1, 2, 3]
for person_id in list_active_fugitives:
    person = db.session.query(models.Person).filter(models.Person.external_id == person_id)
    person[0].is_active = True
    db.session.commit()
```

My goal is to update a value `is_active` for all records with correct `external_id` column.
`external_id` is a unique for each row.
Can I do it without iterate over each record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this by using `._in` function

```
res = db.session.query(models.Person).filter(models.Person.external_id._in(list_active_fugitives ))
 for row in res:
      row.is_active = True
      db.session.commit()
```